# On small resolution, one div overlay another (flex)

Tags: css, responsive

i have this code

```css
 .div1{
      width:100%;
    }
    .div2{
      width:100%;
    }
    .div3{
      width:100%;
    }
    .div4{
      width:100%;
    }

    @media(max-width:800px){
      .div1,.div2,.div3,.div4{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
      }
      .flexyy{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex: 1; 
        flex-wrap:wrap;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class='flexyy'>
      <div class='div1'>....</div>
      <div class='div2'>....</div>
      <div class='div3'>....</div>
      <div class='div4'>....</div>
    </div>
```

when i resize the browser below 800px. The div3 overlay on div2 and i dont want this.
I want every div to have 100% width
Please help and sorry for my bad english
Thanks in advance

Comment: No need to give width:100% to divs, Div is an block level element. and I am not seeing any issue in your code except dot(.) in div's class names.

Comment: add dots in css before the div1, div2, div3, div4 classes. and I checked your code, your code is working well. there is no overlap of divs on each other.

Comment: i have plce dots. i wrote it here wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css grids + fractional units(fr)

*refactored code:*

**HTML**

```
<div class='flexyy'>
    <div>....</div>
    <div>....</div>
    <div>....</div>
    <div>....</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flexyy {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add  box-sizing:border-box; may be it will help you

```css
   * {
      box-sizing:border-box;
       }
    .div{
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding:5px;
    }
     .flexyy{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
         flex: 1; 
         text-align: justify;
         }

    @media(max-width:800px){

      .flexyy{
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class='flexyy'>
          <div class='div'>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has
          </div>
           <div class='div'>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has
          </div> <div class='div'>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has
          </div> <div class='div'>
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has
          </div>
        </div
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to wrap content. I want to display on screen one div

Comment: @frontjim add wrap .. what do you need ?

Comment: @frontjim add box-sizing:border-box; to all .. i update my ans now check ...